# Get value of another column in an ant.design Table's column?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, antd

In my react and [ant.design](https://ant.design/) based app, I've a table with the following columns.

```
const tableColumns = [{
      title : 'Lorem',
      dataIndex : 'lorem'
      render: text => <a href='#'> {text + ipsum} </a>
    }, {
      title : 'Ipsum',
      dataIndex : 'ipsum'
    }];
```

I want to use value for `ipsum` i.e. the second column for each row inside render function of the first column. What's the best recommended way in [ant.design](https://ant.design/) to fetch second column's value here?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The second argument to the render function is the current record:

```
render: (text, row) => <a> {text + row.ipsum} </a>
```

https://ant.design/components/table/#Column