# Using antd column render to display percentage of another column

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

Another probably simple problem I'm overlooking. Within my columns:

```
    {
      title: 'Min. Value',
      dataIndex: 'min_value',
      render: min_value => `${min_value}`,
      width: '10',
    },
    {
      title: 'Max Value',
      dataIndex: 'max_value',
      render: max_value => `${max_value}`,
      width: '15',
    },
    {
      title: 'Min. Commission',
      dataIndex: 'min_commission',
      render: row => {row.min_value},
      width: '15',
    },
    {
      title: 'Max Commission',
      dataIndex: 'max_commission',
      render: max_value => `${max_value}`,
      width: '15',
    },
```

I'm trying to use the `render` option in `min_commission` and `max_commission` to display a percentage of their respective min/max value columns. What's shown currently in `min_commission` is just trying to display the data from `min_value`.

Which just gives the error:

```
Failed to compile
./src/components/LeaderBoard.js
  Line 65:23:  Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Search for the keywords to learn more about each error.
```

I've been a bit stuck just trying to display the data from the other column. I feel like that's the first step I need before I can worry about adding in a percentage calculation, I just can't work out how to pull the data. The current `row => {row.min_value}` was based off another thread I had found with an almost similar situation, so I thought it might work.

Comment: are you sure the ```row.min_value``` is value not a function? do a console.log inside the arrow function and return some static string for now, and see the value of ```row.min_value```

Comment: @Anuja so something like `render: row => {'test', console.log(row.min_value)},` ? page displays same error, console displays `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'min_value' of undefined` so I've definitely got something backwards hah! 

Comment: how you are doing the function is wrong, do like this:
```render: row => { console.log({row}); return 'test' }```
and check whats inside the whole ```row``` object and if there is a ```min_value``` property and if it is a function or ```undefined```

Comment: Ahh, I see. That makes a big difference. This logs `undefined`, so I am using it wrong. I need to spend some time better understanding antd column render. The post I was referencing was https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44924766/get-value-of-another-column-in-an-ant-design-tables-column, but I'm not working it out correctly at all. Thank you!

Comment: yeah read the latest documentation, I personally havent used antdesign but its possible the api has been updated and the answer is out of date. Safer to stick to documentation.